# NullPointerException while passing data through Intent

Tags: android

I wanted to pass a selected menu name in listview to another intent class so that the new submenu is recognized by its parent-menu. So I used the getExtras to get Menu name as belows in KatagoriPengeluaran.java

```
 public void displayListView() {



listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
     int position, long id) {

       Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

       String countryCode = 
        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("katagori_label"));   
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(KatagoriPengeluaran.this, Pengeluaran.class);
        ourIntent.putExtra("cek", countryCode);

       startActivity(ourIntent);
   }
  });
```

And in the new class which is Pengeluaran.java

```
    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.pengeluaran);

  dbHelper = new Database(this);
  dbHelper.open();

    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    String sub = extras.getString("cek");

// dbHelper.deleteAllData();
 //dbHelper.insertSomeData();

  //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
  displayListView(sub);

 }


         private void displayListView(final String su) {


  cursor = dbHelper.fetchPengeluaran(su);

  // The desired columns to be bound
  allAdapter = new PengeluaranCursorAdapter(this, cursor);

  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  // Assign adapter to ListView
  listView.setAdapter(allAdapter);
```

Here's my database and the fetch function

```
    public class Database {
// Katagori Pengeluaran
    public static final String RIK = "_id";
    public static final String RLK = "katagori_label";
    public static final String RJK = "katagori_jumlah";

    //Pengeluaran

    public static final String KEY_RPI = "_id";
     public static final String KEY_RLP = "pengeluaran_label";
     public static final String KEY_RSK = "pengeluaran_sub";
     public static final String KEY_RNP = "nominal";
     public static final String KEY_RTP = "tanggal";



        public Cursor fetchPengeluaran(String su) {

  Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(PENGELUARAN_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_RPI,
    KEY_RLP, KEY_RSK, KEY_RNP, KEY_RTP}, "KEY_RLP like " + su
  ,null, null, null, null);

  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;
 }
```

But while executing it says NullPointerException, Unable to Inisiate Activity Component in the log cat. Please help.

Comment: Have you declared the activity in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Post a stack trace from logcat

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to `getExtra`

```
sub = (String) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cek");
```

**EDIT**

Just you `Log.i("Activity", countryCode );`

To make your your `countrycode` is not null

Comment: Log is not the way to go to check if items are null. Use the debugger and check with a breakpoint what the value for that variable is. Log is good for logging information, not for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

**Why do you get a cursor back from your listView?** That doesn't look like a good idea to me. You should separate presentation and data.

You can try using the following in the first class instead. Use `putString()` instead of `putExtra()`

```
ourIntent.putString("cek", countryCode);
```

#### ListView & Adapter

Other than that I can't find anything I would do different. But like I said in the first place, review having a `cursor` object in your presentation (`listView`). Instead have String objects in an `ArrayAdapter` for example so you can get the `String` countryCode directly.

More information on listViews here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

#### Debug

Anyway I would double check in debug mode that the object returned from your `Cursor` is what you expect and most of all not `null`.